# FabricJS + Node not being able to set up backgroundImage via nodeJs fabric

Tags: javascript, node.js, fabricjs

I'm not being able to set a background on the FabricJs using the node-canvas, I'm probably doing it wrong, but I couldn't find anywhere online of what I really need to do.

The only code I see is the normal Node, but no place teaching what exactly I have to do

So when I write the following code, everything I get is the final image with everything I've added but transparent background.

```
var out = fs.createWriteStream('public/server/_tempImg/slideTeste.png');
var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(800,450);

var text = new fabric.Textbox('Testing Slide with background', {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    textAlign: "center",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    fontSize: 40,
    width: 500,
    fill: '#000000'
});

canvas.add(text);
canvas.centerObject(text);


canvas.setBackgroundImage('public/img/bg_bookeh1.jpg',
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();

stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    out.write(chunk);
});

stream.on('end', function(data){
    //console.log('Salvou imagem');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I've also tried setting it with different images

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://localhost:3000/img/bg_bookeh1.jpg',
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is the image not loading before the image is exported via Node?

This is the image I'm getting. A PNG with transparent background.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tslo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was exactly NOT loading the image before so the right way to do it was.

```
var out = fs.createWriteStream('public/server/_tempImg/slideTeste.png');
var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(800,450);

var text = new fabric.Textbox('Testing Slide with background', {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    textAlign: "center",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    fontSize: 40,
    width: 500,
    fill: '#000000'
});

canvas.add(text);
canvas.centerObject(text);

//load the image first
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://localhost:3000/img/bg_bookeh1.jpg', function(myImg){

    var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();

    canvas.setBackgroundImage(myImg,
        canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        out.write(chunk);
    });

    stream.on('end', function(data){
        //console.log('Salvou imagem');
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });

});
```

The real different is loading the image with

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://localhost:3000/img/bg_bookeh1.jpg', function(myImg){
```

and than doing the creation of the image after it was loaded.

```
stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    out.write(chunk);
});

stream.on('end', function(data){
    //console.log('Salvou imagem');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```